# Unwind works properly until I add a prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I need help with this app I am building. If you need to see the full code, I can post it, but here is the scenario:

I have 3 `UIViewControllers`, `SMPViewController`, `SMPLetterViewController` and `SMPDetailsViewController`.

In `SMPViewController` I have a `prepareForSegue`, and an UnWind:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    SMPLetterViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    destination.lblSectionText = _lblForSectionTitles;
}
-(IBAction)returnToMain:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{
    //just return to Home page
}
```

In `SMPLetterViewController` I have a prepareForSegue, an UnWind and a button titled, “Back” that connects with the UnWind of the `SMPViewController`:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    SMPDetailsViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    destination.lblTextLetter = _lblWordSort;
}

-(IBAction)returnToLetterList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{
    //just return to Letter page
}
```

In the `SMPDetailsViewController`, I have a button titled, “Home” which connects the UnWind of the `SMPViewController`, and a button titled, “Back” which connects with the UnWind of the `SMPLetterViewController`.

When I run the program everything is working properly except the Back button on the `SMPLetterViewController`, it keeps crashing my App. with an error telling me something is wrong with the `lblTextLetter` in the prepareForSegue in the `SMPLetterViewController`. When I comment out the `prepareForSegue` in the `SMPLetterViewController` everything works great, except I cannot transfer the information to the `SMPDetailsViewController`.

To me the prepareForSegue’s in both the `SMPViewController` and `SMPLetterViewController` syntax is correct so why does it not work and why is it singling out the lblTextLetter?

Any ideas as to what is wrong? Do I just need another pair of eyes as I am missing something?

Thanks for any help,
socamorti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In storyboard add segue identifier and change your prepareForSegue to something like that:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER"]) {
        SMPDetailsViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        destination.lblTextLetter = _lblWordSort;
    }
}
```

And do something like that for your second prepareForSegue as well.
This issue happens because when you run unwind action the prepareForSegue is called as well.

Comment: Thanks, it works as the app is not crashing anymore, however, since I am new to this, it is not passing on the info to the next view controller. I believe this is because it is in a decision. So my follow up question is, how do I set the segue identifier? or do I just place the line where I am passing the info to the next view after the if statement?

Comment: Ok, found where to set the segue identifier and everything works great. Thanks for the help it was much appreciated.

Comment: Anyone know if it is expected behavior for prepareForSeque to fire on both unwind AND segue to next screen?